# Querying in Jira for Fix Version with more than one value?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to query in `Jira` for multiple values in the fix version field?  To clarify, I want to find just issues where there is more than one fix version on the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The "IN" operator is used to search for issues where the value of the specified field is *one* of multiple specified values. So it doesn't work for the case here where there's more than one fixVersion value.  As of Jira 6.4.x there's really no way to do what you're asking.

A search like fixVersion in ("1.0.0.0","1.1.0.0") has the following possible results:

Matches:

```
fixVersion = 1.0.0.0 
fixVersion = 1.0.0.0,1.2.0.0
fixVersion = 1.1.0.0
```

Does not Match:

```
fixVersion = 1.0.0.0, 1.1.0.0 
fixVersion = 1.2.0.0
```

You'll notice the strange result in the matches section.  You get a match if just ONE of the matching targets is in the list of fixVersions for an issue. If both of them are in the fixVersion list it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this when there is a known reference version.

```
(fixVersion  <= 206 AND fixVersion > 206) or (fixVersion  >= 206 AND fixVersion < 206)
```

206 is my current main release number (note this is not the version name) and other patches are delivered along side this release so some issues have multiple fix versions.

JIRA v8.5.4

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the most optimized query but this worked

```
fixversion=1.0.0.0 OR fixversion=1.1.0.0
```

I was using JIRA v6.4.11 atm